# How to correct this Ajax Request in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to send ajax request to fetch data from controller when I change date. I am not able to write ajax code properly. My code is as under:

```html
{!!Form::open(['action' => 'BookingsController@store', 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
   @csrf


  <input type="date" name="eventDate" id="eventDate" value="">


  <select name="vehicleName" id="vehicleName">
       <option disabled selected>Choose Vehicle...</option>
  <?php foreach ($availableVehicles as $key => $vehicle): ?>
     <option id="{{$vehicle->id}}">{{$vehicle->name}} </option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>

 {!!Form::close()!!}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(#eventDate).change(function(){
      var eventDate = $(this).val();
 
      $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('booking.create') }}",
        method:"GET",
        data:{eventDate},
        success:function(result){
          $('#vehicleName').val('');
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the issue in AJAX request it is not sent or it is giving any error?

Comment: I couldn't code it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** You need to add into your data attribute the token variable token. Because Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application.

```
data{'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
```

**2)** You forgot to add quotes into your #eventDate function. Change this:

```
$(#eventDate).change(function(){
```

to this

```
$('#eventDate').change(function(){
```

**3)** My opinion is to create the ajax inside the `.change()` function. Here is a full code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#eventDate').change(function(){
     var eventDate = $(this).val();

     $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('booking.create') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}','eventDate' : eventDate },
        success:function(result){
            $('#vehicleName').val('');
        },
     });
  });
});
```

I hope it helped you

**EDITED**

You can create a meta element inside your **master layout** like the example below.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Furthermore, inside your jQuery scripts you can call it:

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

This is better, because you can use **csrf_token** inside **js** files

Comment: I just want to submit the $request value to control onchange. out will be automatically generated. How can I send?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have $eventDate variable in the controller. I want to pass that value without submitting the form.   for instance I ve a resource controller . In that controller I ve public function create(){} and public function store().. What I want I want to get the data of $availableVehicles from create(). If I submit the form it will go to store().

Comment: That's a clompletly different question, it would be nice if you accept his answer.

Comment: Yeah Ali, just accept the answer and ask another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid form being submitted you should add:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // to track it is working: console.log( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: I have accepted his answer. Should I used it with Ajax request? Actually I am not understanding how to pass the value of this #eventDate to controller@create.. After loading form I have to select date from form that value will be sent to the controller for querry variable. After that the values accordingly change into the form like depend drop downs but here I' ve different tables from which I ll bring values here. After that I will submit the form that $request will be made on controller@store. I hope you got  my question

Comment: As I understand, you need 2 different requests: 1 for refill select items based on #eventDate and 2) after a car has been selected, to send  the whole form to controller@store. For the first one, Nikolas answer is the right one. For the second, you have to add a 'submit' button and on its click, build a request with full data.